# BigQuery: Array index 1 is out of bounds (overflow) [Finding distinct counts for ALL columns without specifying column names)

Tags: sql, google-bigquery, distinct-values

On Bigquery, I have a table with many columns. I want to create a new table showing counts of all distinct values for all columns.

I am using the below code:

```
SELECT key AS column_name,
COUNT(DISTINCT val) AS number_of_options,
ARRAY_AGG(DISTINCT val) AS distinct_options
FROM (
  SELECT TRIM(x[0], '"') AS key, 
  TRIM(x[1], '"') AS val
  FROM t,
  UNNEST(SPLIT(TRIM(TO_JSON_STRING(t), '{}'), ',"')) kv,   
  UNNEST([STRUCT(SPLIT(kv, '":') AS x)])
  )
GROUP BY key
```

The above code saves me from specifying all column names or looping over them. But this throws the error 'Array index 1 is out of bounds (overflow)'. Without referencing x[1] (which contains the value for each row-column), the code works fine. I tried adding 'where x[1] is not null', etc., but everytime the code throws the above error.

Will appreciate any help. Can elaborate more if needed.

Answer (score 0):

Using x[safe_offset(1)] worked!

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).